# Gunner bot programing

Tags: programming, rcx

I just build the RCX Gunner Bot using the instructions from [this](http://www.legomylegobot.com/lego%20nxt%20rcx%20projects_007.htm) web site.

I had to build something different to the one we built in the class, I added a touch sensor and light sensor, so the bot will avoid any obstacles on its way, and shoot when it sees a black dot.

I am wondering if anyone has a program for a basic gunner bot, or at least for shooting the bullets. If somebody can help me, It would really appreciated.
I am not an engineering person but I need to pass that class.

Comment: Are you setup to use NQC?

Comment: no, I have to use RCX Code

Comment: Please state clearly what problems you have as well as what you have tried.

Comment: I used: ON motor B then Set Direction Bv then Set Power B(8) and the bot is shooting but non stop. How to make it drive then shoot two times if it hits something or shoot if it sees a black spot?

Answer (score 6):

Your code handling the behaviours like "Shoot 3 times if the touch sensor is triggered" or "Shoot if the light sensor is triggered" should use 'if' statements.

[image]

Then, instead of always being called, the "shooting" code would append only on sensor events.  After shooting, the robot would then go back to the "Driving around" part of the code.

[This page](http://llk.media.mit.edu/projects/cricket/doc/help/logoblocks/ref-rcx.html) is a good visual reference for all the RCX programming components

Comment: @ewelina does this help in any way?